# WPF Errorlist, UI Element types

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I want to know which WPF UI-Elements microsoft uses in the error list of VS2015

Heres a little picture. The datagrid is clearly but is the panel above a StatusBar? 
[image]

Comment: Top panel could be `ToolBar`, but you can't be sure 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspected with Snoop it brings the following up:

[image: Vs2015 Screen]

So it seems to be basically a ToolBar

The Grid is an *ErrorHubControl*

Comment: Thanks lokusking, excatly what I searched for :-)